# Woocommerce Sorting

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

A wordpress site that I have Woocommerce on just recently started doing something strange. The product sorting, after choosing a category, does not work. I have been searching around trying to figure out where I can correct this, but nothing I find has really helped.

I am looking for the main file that controls this sorting. I don't know if it would be the wordpress template or the woocommerce files themselves.

Does anyone know what file controls the product sorting? Also would updating Wordpress potentially fix this? I see that I have an update due.

Here is a screenshot for illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of WooCommerce?
Are the templates related to WooCommerce are override by the theme?

If you are templates are override by the theme, then may be your theme is loading an outdated WooCommerce template file, which could be the culprit.
Please try to update, if applicable.

I would suggest updating them, if applicable: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/fix-outdated-templates-woocommerce/.

That should may help in solving the issue.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know.